# Error: "warning C4005: 'SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR': macro redefinition"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, swig

I'm trying to compile a `SWIG` project, and it keeps on giving errors like this:

> swig_wrap.cpp(55): warning C4005: 'SWIGTEMPLATEDISAMBIGUATOR': macro
>   redefinition

And errors like this:

> fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
>   header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

#### Compiler

- Visual Studio 2015+Update 3.
- SWIG v3.0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `.i` file:

```
%begin %{
#include "stdafx.h"
%}
```

This section injects code into the generated wrapper at the top of the file and you won't need to disable pre-compiled headers.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I had a decent go at trying to find a solution like this, but missed finding the `begin` keyword in the docs. This is by far the most elegant answer, it works well for both Debug and Release without fiddling with Visual Studio settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, right click on the swig-generated `.cpp` wrapper file, and select "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

In my case, the wrapper file that swig auto-generated was `swig_wrap.cpp`.

You can leave precompiled headers on for the entire project.

For more info, see nabble.com and [Fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/fatal-error-C1010-unexpected-end-of-file-while-looking-for-precompiled-header-Did-you-forget-to-add--td8409.html)

[image]

---

#### Appendix A: SWIG could be fixed to avoid this!

Another way to fix this is to manually add the line "stdafx.h" to the start of this file, but unfortunately, every time `swig` is run it will remove this fix! There is a way to fix this, but its not at all obvious (see the other answer).